# New VS Project Creation to interface with SOAF service

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, soaf

I don't create VS projects normally; it's been mostly changes to existing ones so far, and I'm fairly new to VS, and I'm the only real software engineer on my team.  I've done project creation for tutorials, but this is new and doesn't follow a tutorial that I see.

I'm trying to create a VS project that is like another one, which shows it's Target framework is .net framework 4.5, console application.  Building it is creating an .exe file and .pdb file in the bin/debug dir.

Then there's my new project that I need to create.  When I created a new VS project, trying to follow the same setup, it created a .net core 3.1 framework (didn't show .net framework 4.5 to choose, and it wasn't showing in project application setup to choose .net framework 4.5), console application, and building it creates a dll with the project name, but also dll's for win32.registry, system.data.sqlclient, system.diagnostics.eventlog, project.exe, project.pdb, runtimeconfig.dev.json, etc, and it's all in bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1.  The plan is to run the .exe with a batch file like the other one, which is why I chose that one to copy the project style.

The solution architect said we need a SOAF service. He said:
•   The Parent program's Web Services Interface - SOA Fabric-enabled (SOAF) web services in the Parent program are Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) web services with support for enhanced security and other features provided through SOAF.
•   AddTask Service – A SOAF service, AddTask operation receives task information from an external task-generating system and adds the task to the parent program for a specific user or a queue. This operation adds a task to either a queue or to a specific user.

My questions are:

1. Does it matter that I have that bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1 folder with all of those dlls' and exe, etc, whereas the old format had just bin/debug/exe and pdb in it?  My plan is to copy the .exe file and none of the .dll's to run for the batch.
2. How do I create a SOAF service, and is that the right kind of project for that?  I don't turn up anything in a search for SOAF service visual studio.

I'm sorry if I'm a little unsure of this, but it's pretty new to me. This uses Visual Studio 2019.

Here is the header info in the Code Sample that uses the TaskService (note that we will also be passing client credentials in ws-security token):

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Tests.Integration.TaskServiceReference;
using Trizetto.CareAdvance.Service.Operation.Tests.Integration;

namespace Tests.Integration.TaskService
{
    internal class Client : ISOAFServicesClient
    {
```

Comment: To create a same project, you need to select project template `Console App(.NET Framework)`.

Comment: I see .net framework developer pack 4.8.  Is that what I need? I think I'd need to install that from the internet.

Comment: You can install the pack via VS installer -> Modify -> Individual Components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed framework 4.8 through VS under target frameworks. It wasn't selectable there, under project properties as I would expect.

I wound up having to re-create my VS project. For template, I found framework 4.8 through searching templates in project creation using framework c# console search params. I then copied my files over to the new project folder, and added them as existing items through the solution tool.

I'm still not entirely sure about the SOAF part.